# Не работает ссылка, помогите разобратся

Tags: html, css

знатоки... Появилась проблема, которая очень банальная, но сам не могу разобраться. Есть у меня значит вверху HEADER, а в нем есть несколько кнопок, которые должны вести на нужную мне страницу... Но вот беда, ссылки эти не реагируют на нажатие.. что же делать, и куда копать? Запуск проходит на Live Server в VS Code, поэтому ссылки в таком виде должны работать адекватно.

HTML

```
    <header>
    <div class="header-button">
        <div><a href="/Index.html"><img src="img/ico/home.png"></a></div>
        <div><a href="/Search.html"><img src="img/ico/search.png"></a></div>
        <div><a href="/Mail.html"><img src="img/ico/email.png"></a></div>
        <div><a href="/Notification.html"><img src="img/ico/notification.png"></a></div>
        <div><a href="/Apps.html"><img src="img/ico/apps.png"></a></div>
    </div>
    </header>
```

CSS

```
    header {
    position: fixed;
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    height: 46;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: white;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 4px gainsboro;
    }
    .header-button {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    height: 24;
    justify-content: space-around;
    }
    .header-button > div > img {
    width: 24;
    height: 24;
    cursor: pointer;
    filter: opacity(40%);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Согласно написаному вами, файлы `Index.html, Search.html ...`, что бы браузер по ним переходил должны находиться на уровень выше текущего исполняемого файла (только надо "../Search.html").(если же они в той же дериктории то уберите `/`) Желательно название файлов писать с маленьких букв.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
       <header>
    <div class="header-button">
        <div><a href="Index.html"><img src="img/ico/home.png"></a></div>
        <div><a href="../Search.html">Search</a></div>
        <div><a href="Mail.html">MAIL</a></div>
    </div>
    </header>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: пробовал, не помогает.. Отклика нет((касаемо уровня, то сам vs code не видит файла без слеша

Comment: Всё там работает. Перепроверил у себя на машине. Вы не правильно указываете деррикторию вызова файлов.

Comment: Тогда я ничего не пойму((( у меня не работает((( слеш убирал, с маленькой буквы писал... не хочет и все((((

Comment: ок, начнем с начала. У вас файлы указанные в href ссылок, находяться в той же дерриктории что и index.html?

Comment: Да, они находятся там же, где и сам Index

Comment: Ok, тогда просто у всех href удалите `/` . Название файлов вызываемых и те что в href должны совпадать.   Index.html и index.html и InDeX.html это 3 разных файла

Comment: У меня есть TeamViewer, если есть возможность, то могу подключить удаленку, и сами убедитесь, в том что не работает

Comment: Появилась другая проблема, теперь ссылки ломают стили

Comment: Проблема всё таже. Вот информация https://htmlacademy.ru/blog/html/links https://htmlacademy.ru/blog/html/ahref Пока не разберетесь с подключениями файлов оно будет продолжать ломаться.

Comment: с ссылками разобрался... проблема была в моей голове((( У меня дублировался HEADER.. я по не понятной причине добавил его и вверху кода, и внизу... когда убрал один дубль, ссылки заработали, но теперь они ломают стиль  присвоенный тегу IMG

Comment: у вас проблемы с относительными путями. то, что вызывается в файле index.html не всегда совпадает с такими же адресами в других файлах. Я думаю что вы путаете стили с `src=` это про разное.  Прочитайте указанные статьи, там толково объясняют значения.